# Manifolds are paracompact

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

By Definition, smooth manifolds are assumed to be Hausdorff and to satisfy the second countability axiom.
I have heard (but never seen written) that these assumptions imply paracompactness (and thus the existence of a Riemannian metric by the well-known construction using Partition of unity). 
Does anybody know a reference or Proof for paracompactness?

Comment: The proof is in most introductory manifold theory textbooks, usually immediately before the construction of partitions of unity.   Try Conlon's *Differentiable Manifolds* for example. 

Comment: More generally, a regular Lindelöf space is paracompact. This should be proved in general topology texts.

Comment: Oh come on guys, it's all too easy to click on the close button instead of answering the question.  I thought it was useful to give a self-contained answer.  Yes, the answer in Conlon is similar, but even there, more spread out.

Comment: @Greg, that seems like a rather narrow reading of what happened here.  I'm having a hard time thinking of an introductory manifold theory textbook that does not cover this topic, one way or another.

Comment: @Ryan Fair enough.  Still, if MathOverflow builds up a Wikipedia-like library of answers, even those that appear in textbooks, that's not such a bad thing.

Comment: You may have a look into John M Lee's second volume on manifolds, "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". It is an extensive work on **basically everything!!** about smooth manifolds one could even think of, in particular, chapter 1 section 1 subsection "Local Compactness and Paracompactness" proposition 1.12, addresses exactly your question. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Theorem: A countable atlas of charts for a Hausdorff $n$-manifold $M$ can be refined to a locally finite atlas.  In fact, each chart only needs to be trimmed.

Proof: Let $U_1,U_2,\ldots$ be the charts.  Each $U_i$, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is the limit of a nested sequence of compact subsets $K_{i,1} \subseteq K_{i,2} \subseteq \ldots$.   Since $M$ is Hausdorff, each $K_{i,j}$ is closed in $M$.  So it suffices to delete
$K_{1,i} \cup \cdots \cup K_{i-1,i}$ from $U_i$ to make a new chart $V_i$.  Some of the $V_i$ might be empty, but this is no problem.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Take $M = \mathbb{R}$; let $U_i = \mathbb{R}$ for all $i$, mapped identically into $M$; let $K_{i, j} = K_j = [-j, -\frac{1}{j}] \cup [\frac{1}{j}, j]$, independently of $i$. Then $V_i$ is simply the complement of $K_i$, but the family formed by the $V_i$ is not locally finite, as they all contain $0$. Or did I miss something?

Comment: The condition on the K's means that each U is the union of the corresponding K's; yours don't satisfy this requirement. Your revised example does clearly show that an emendation to the original argument is needed; the following seems to suffice: Require of the sets K that the interiors of those associated with any U exhaust the corresponding U. One easily sees that any given K--and so, a fortiori, the interior of any given K--meets only finitely many V's. Since any point belongs to the interior of some K, local finiteness of the covering by the V's is thus established.

Comment: @IliaSmilga You need to take compact sets whose union is $U_i$, not just whose union is dense in  $U_i$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. So let's take $K_j = [-j,0] \cup [\frac{1}{j},j]$. Then they do indeed exhaust $\mathbb{R}$; but the family of their complements $V_i$ is still not locally finite, since any neighborhood of $0$ intersects infinitely many of them.

Comment: Equivalently, since we are working on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can just change one symbol in the proof: instead of $\subset$ use $\Subset$ for the relation between the $K$s.

Comment: What does the notation $X \Subset Y$ mean? (Guessing from context: it means that $X$ is contained in the interior of $Y$, right?)

Comment: @IliaSmilga that's usually the symbol used for compact embedding, so means that the *closure* of $X$ is contained in the interior of $Y$. Since $K$s are compact, the "closure" part is superfluous in context.