# Is a manifold paracompact? Should it be?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

We will say that a Hausdorff topological space $X$ is a smooth manifold if there is an open cover $(U_{\alpha})$ of $X$ and a corresponding collection of homeomorphisms $\varphi_{\alpha} : U_{\alpha} \to V_{\alpha} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that on any overlap $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$, the maps $$\varphi_{\beta} \circ \varphi_{\alpha}^{-1} : \varphi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}) \longrightarrow \varphi_{\beta}(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta})$$ are smooth.

Note that I have omitted the assumption of paracompactness. I recall vaguely from my undergraduate years of my lecturer telling us that there are good reasons for omitting paracompactness from the definition of a manifold unless one wants to look at metric properties of $X$ or integrate.

His expertise was in complex geometry and homogenous spaces. I vaguely recall his justification for this being that every group can be declared a Lie group if one allows the more general definition since one is permitted to have an uncountable number of connected components.

I am not sure if I have correctly remembered this, but I was hoping someone could maybe elaborate on this thought further?

Comment: Sure, every discrete group is a zero-dimensional Lie group. There are examples of locally convex infinite-dimensional manifolds that aren't paracompact, but if one is happy to go there, then mere lack of paracompactness won't be scary. Note that the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) is a 1-dimensional manifold-without-paracompactness, and doesn't have a Riemannian metric inducing its topology. This is one reason why one might want to insist on paracompactness.

Comment: I removed the mathematical philosophy tag as I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Manifolds are paracompact](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96780/manifolds-are-paracompact?rq=1).

Comment: @abx the accepted answer there says that if a manifold is covered by countably many charts then it is paracompact.

Comment: What's not clear to me is whether a connected Hausdorff smooth manifold has to be paracompact (it's false for topological manifolds).

Comment: @YCor: Doesn't the long line admit a differentiable structure?

Comment: @abx I never heard so, and never heard the contrary. But indeed it's said on the Wikipedia page that it does.

Comment: If one thinks he or she understand surfaces, then one thinks of manifolds as paracompact. The variety of non-paracompact surfaces is **wild**.

Comment: I get the feeling that whether manifolds are paracompact by definition is (perhaps on a different level of severity) a discussion similar to [whether rings have units](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/does-anyone-believe-that-there-are-rings-without-unit-elements) (even the algebra/analysis divide seems to be the same: the "every group is a Lie group" POV can be declared as algebraic, while the "differential geometry goes out of the window" POV is analytic)

Comment: @WillieWong: although the algebra/analysis divide is "flipped" in this case, with respect to requiring "more" properties to deserve the name, right?

Comment: @YCor: A related pathology: Rado proved that all connected 1-dimensional complex manifolds are 2nd countable, but there exist connected 2-dimensional non-second-countable complex manifolds.  Volume 1 of Hubbard's treatise on Teichmuller theory contains a nice discussion of this.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Hah, you are of course right. I didn't even try to think in that level of detail (was focusing more on how again there is tension between algebra and analysis in terms of what is convenient).

Comment: Your question appears to be just seeking opinions. i.e. is this a MathOverflow question?   To give it some structure you should perhaps explain what you want to use the notion of manifold for.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Manifolds being paracompact is hardly a matter of opinion, unless you are willing to declare the vast majority of theorems (examples: existence of Riemannian metrics, existence of connections, existence of embeddings in R^n) in any textbook on smooth manifolds to be false.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: I think we might be miscommunicating.  This thread is asking for an opinion on what the appropriate definition of a manifold should be.  The only way to answer such a question (without bringing in personal prejudices) is if the question-asker has some sort of purpose for using the notion of manifold. I fully agree manifold theory has a history and has settled on its definitions with good reasons. But this question does not appear to be about that.  As far as I can tell, the question could be "removing paracompactness from the manifold definition, is the notion interesting?"

Comment: It's difficult to declare a notion interesting without some sort of criterion being given.  Anyhow, I'll stop commenting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> every group can be declared a Lie group if one allows the more general definition since one is permitted to have an uncountable number of connected components.

A manifold is paracompact if and only if all of its connected components are second countable.
So in particular, any discrete group is a paracompact Hausdorff smooth manifold.
This manifold is second countable if and only if the group is countable,
so if we want uncountable discrete groups to be Lie groups,
we cannot require manifolds to be second countable, only paracompact.

On the other hand, removing the weaker assumption of paracompactness from the definition
of a smooth manifold will immediately eliminate all theorems
that use partitions of unity (examples: existence of Riemannian metrics, existence of connections, existence of embeddings in R^n, the Serre–Swan theorem),
which in the context of differential geometry
means the vast majority of nontrivial theorems.
Unless one intends to make all these theorems false,
it probably makes sense to make manifolds paracompact by definition.

Answer (score 6):

Another good gift of paracompactness:

> A Hausdorff $C^k$ manifold ($k\ge0$) is metrizable iff it is
>   paracompact.

This is also true for infinite dimensional manifold modelled on a Banach space (because the underlying fact is that a topological space is metrisable iff it is Hausdorff, paracompact and locally metrisable: local metrics may be glued by means of a partition of unity).

Talking about Banach manifolds, recall, just in case, that

> A second countable, *regular*, Banach manifold is paracompact.

But here  *Hausdorff*  in place of *regular*  only gives an equivalent statement in finite dimension: it would be false for infinite dimensional Banach manifolds. (An enjoyable account of this in in R.Palais' paper *Critical point theory and the minimax principle*)